# Expandable/Collapse layout in RecyclerView - Fetch API and create dynamic view in expandable layout not showing data when scrolled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Kindly help me out for this situation.

I'm having recyclerview and on view click I used your library for expand and collapse. Issue here is expandableview layout has been created dynamically based on the API response. So on the time of API loading if I scroll the layout then the view not updated with the records from API.

I'm calling the API only on click of recyclerview item row and fetching the API and constructing the layout.

onBindViewHolder will get called on scroll and view got refreshed. But I'm not sure how to load childview data when scrolled.

I inserted "notifyItemChanged" in OnBindHolder but it throws exception layout can be refreshed on scroll Illegal state exception. Kindly share your thoughts.

Library which I used inside RecyclerView view for expand/collapse - https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cause for the above issue:

1. Calling API on click of child view and store the response in model.
2. Make the child view model getter/setter in Parent view itself which will be easy to reload the view.
3. Don't get the holder reference in API Success call method and set the values for child view. When API getting called in background if we scroll then view holder reference will get changed. Which makes particular row values not updated on scroll.

Solution would be:

Create Parent model with child model values too as getter/setter refrence.
Then now as-usual create your view adapter which parent model values
On Child View click fetch API response and store in model and call notifydatasetchanged function.
Then in your onBindViewHolder method make a condition if(Selpos == clickedposition) then call your dynamic view method which updates the values from model.